# Excel Pivot or Powerpivot Sum Items in Row Labels

Tags: excel-formula

I have a database with multiple entries for the dollar amount of an order (with unique order number).  In my pivot table, I only want the sale dollar amount shown once (not summed), which I have accomplished by putting this field in the "row labels" function.  However, I want to total all of these sale dollar amount values shown in the pivot table by date.  How can I accomplish this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have `date` above `dollar amount of an order` in ROWS and Sum of `dollar amount of an order` in Σ VALUES.